How to copy/paste text into Weston?
How to copy/paste text into Weston? My current steps:

I copy some text from outside of Weston (in X11)
I switch to an app inside Weston
I click "paste" (Ctrl+V)

Expected at this point: the text gets pasted.
Actually at this point: nothing gets pasted. The clipboards are completely separated.
The manual pages man weston and man weston.ini do not mention the clipboard.
